# How to position a composite to be at the end of another composite

Tags: java, swt

Parent composite is a scrollForm body. I have a child composite of RowLayout.
I want to add a child composite into a parent composite in such a way that the child composite must always be in the bottom of the composite.

Comment: have you tried vertical alignment

Comment: Depending on the type of dialog you are using you may be able to place buttons on the same row as the dialog buttons.

Comment: Is "scrollForm body" referring to the body of a `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ScrolledForm`? Are you using it in an Eclipse RCP view?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly (some code would help), you shold be able to solve this using a nested `FillLayout` with  type `SWT.VERTICAL`. Cf. the following minimal example taken from [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm).

```
FillLayout fillLayout = new FillLayout();
fillLayout.type = SWT.VERTICAL;
shell.setLayout(fillLayout);
```

Comment: Actually I need to place buttons at the bottom of the screen. Right now what is happening is that, the buttons are placed below the last component in the composite. Say for example if I have a grid of 4 rows, then the buttons are placed after that, but I need to place the buttons at the end of the screen, leaving the blank spaces between the end of the grid and starting of the button. Which layout will help me in acheiving this.

Comment: I think I understand. In this case, try using a 3-row `GridLayout` as parent layout, putting *your* grid in the first row, and the buttons in the third, then tell the second row to grab all of the excess horizontal and vertical space. Cf. http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm for examples of how to do this.